# React Js how to jump whole pages to other pages when click on the navigation button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a react js project which include dual language when click on button eng/chi, My whole Pages need to change to english include header and footer. So i had create 2 .js every file which is chi and eng. 
How do i jump to the EngMainPage when i click on the button? 
In my App.js i using this ways to make it the 1st page when i start the program

```
import ChineseHomePage from './components/pages/Chinese/ChineseHomePage'

<Switch>
   <Route path='/' exact component={ChineseHomePage } />         
</Switch>
```

In my `ChineseHomePage` i use `<Navbar />` to call for the section （under ./components/pages/Chinese/ChineseHomePage) 
In my Navbar i have one part which try to use

```
<li className='nav-item'>
<Link to = {"/WHATSHOULDIPUTHERE"} className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
  中文 / Eng
</Link>
</li>
```

The objective is when i click on the link, i want to redirect the website to a file at `/components/pages/Eng/EngHomePage.js`
which part should i add the `Route path` and what should put in `WHATSHOULDIPUTHERE`

Comment: first of all you should add constants instead make multiple file if your project in initial phase then change the architecture and centralized the internationalization process  and use package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-i18next

Comment: I read the comments and answer, what I would suggest, is to use  i18next, i18next-react. You can follow, following articles:
1- https://medium.com/@tariqul.islam.rony/internationalization-localization-with-react-js-65d6f6badd56
2- https://medium.com/@jishnu61/6-easy-steps-to-localize-your-react-application-internationalization-with-i18next-8de9cc3a66a1

Comment: @Mudassar, i have read several article about i18next. But most of them are translate it in app.js, what if in my `mainpage` i have several section like `navigation` herosection` `footer` which located at different .js file?

Comment: It doesn't matter how much components you have. I use translation using useTranslation() hook from i18next and works fine from me. There are multiple ways to translate the page. Just follow the first link, I followed that and it worked well for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the following methods to fulfill your objective. Personally I prefer method 2 due to that method provides a more robust solution.

### Method 1

Define two routes for each Home page component and navigate to relevant route when needed.

`App.js`

```
import ChineseHomePage from './components/pages/Chinese/ChineseHomePage'
import EnglishHomePage from './components/pages/Eng/EngHomePage'

<Switch>
   <Route path='/ch' exact component={ChineseHomePage} />
   <Route path='/en' exact component={EnglishHomePage} />         
</Switch>
```

`NavBar.js`

```
<li className='nav-item'>
    <Link to="/ch" className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
        中文
    </Link>
    /
    <Link to="/en" className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
        Eng
    </Link>
</li>
```

### Method 2

use an `useState` hook to set your language and render the relevant component according to the set language.

Note: You have to pass the dispatch function of `language` hook from `App.js` to other components as a prop.

`App.js`

```
import ChineseHomePage from './components/pages/Chinese/ChineseHomePage'
import EnglishHomePage from './components/pages/Eng/EngHomePage'

const [language, setLanguage] = useState('eng');

<Switch>
   <Route path='/' exact component={() => {
      language == 'eng' ? (<EnglishHomePage setLanguage={setLanguage} />) : (<ChineseHomePage setLanguage={setLanguage} />)
   }} />        
</Switch>
```

`EngHomePage.js`

```
const EnglishHomePage = ({ setLanguage }) => {
    ...
    <NavBar setLanguage={setLanguage} />
    ...
}
```

`ChineseHomePage.js`

```
const ChineseHomePage = ({ setLanguage }) => {
    ...
    <NavBar setLanguage={setLanguage} />
    ...
}
```

`NavBar`

```
const NavBar = ({ setLanguage }) => {
    ...
    <li className='nav-item'>
        <div className='nav-links' role='button' onClick={() => {
            setLanguage('chi');
            closeMobileMenu();
        }}>
            中文
        </div>
        /
        <div className='nav-links' role='button' onClick={() => {
            setLanguage('eng');
            closeMobileMenu();
        }}>
            Eng
        </div>
    </li>
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but for the method 2 i not sure where is the problem when i try to paste ur code in my project there will be `error underline` under the first `return` and few close `bracket` there. Do you have any idea

Comment: Ah yes @czroo. I have mistakenly added a return statement to ternary operator which is syntactically wrong. And now I fixed that syntax error and now you can follow the method 2 without any error.

Answer (score 2):

I would use same routes and dynamic components like this:

```
...
<Route path='/' exact component={HomePage}/>
...
const HomePage = () => {
   const [lang, setLang] = useState('eng');

   return lang === 'eng' ? <EnglishHomePage/> : <ChineseHomePage/>
}
```